# Preserving a model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view rendering a Model, where Model is changed and posted to an action.
Some properties of the Model are kept unchanged and just need to be passed on to the view.
Eg. Model has properties **Color and Name**:

```
**View:**
Model.Name - used for for something.
Model.Color - not used, just needs to be preserved and passed on to action.

[HttpPost]
**Action:**
String Name = Model.Name
String Color = Model.Color
```

Do I use a hidden field for that ?

Comment: You can pass this data to a view via ViewData or use a strongly typed view.

Comment: @Bernie White, It's already a strongly typed view. And how can I pass it through viewdata from view to action ? The only alternative is posting the field or going through the form values in the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only if `Color` can be different on different requests and you need that `value` after the post.

Another way is to store it in the `Session`.

**The safer way is to store it in the session, because even hidden fields can be manipulated**

**Hidden**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Color)
```

**Session**

```
Session["YourKey"] = Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using ViewModel builders, which I've written [a blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/09/05/populating-asp-net-mvc-viewmodels-using-viewmodelbuilders.aspx) on. As @dknaack says, anything which comes in a request can be manipulated by users, so to ensure my non-editable model properties retain the correct values, I created builder classes which just over-write non-editable values with the appropriate values from the database. This is much cleaner and more secure than using hidden fields in my opinion.